# xml schema using unique with bases

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, unique, radix

I have several data types extending from one another using the base="" identifier. They all eventually extend from one base type that has an ID node. I'd like the schema to be able to look across all of the elements to make sure that the ID is unique for each element.

So far, I have:

```
<effects>
  <ResistanceModificationEffect>
    <ID>fire_resistance</ID>
    <!-- other stuff -->
  </ResistanceModificationEffect>
  <ResistanceModificationEffect>
    <ID>fire_resistance</ID>
    <!-- other stuff -->
  </ResistanceModificationEffect>
</effects>
```

and the schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema 
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="effects">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ResistanceModificationEffect" type="resistanceModificationEffectDef" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
<xs:unique name="uniqueID">
  <xs:selector xpath=".//*"/>
  <xs:field xpath="@ID"/>
</xs:unique>
</xs:element>

</schema>
```

As for the xs:unique element, I've tried various different things to make it see the node with the tag ID as the node to check uniqueness of.

```
  <xs:selector xpath="*"/>
  <xs:selector xpath="./*"/>
  <xs:selector xpath=".//*"/>
```

From all I've read about schemas, all I should need is

```
  <xs:selector xpath="*"/>
```

unless I'm just not understanding it. [This](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/schema/ch09_02.htm) link says at the bottom that "*" is a valid identifier as selecting all the children, and the "@elementName" should select the element to compare.

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

*Facepalm*

Answered my own question using the link I provided above. Using

```
  <xs:field xpath="@ID"/>
```

tries to get an *attribute* from the selected node.

```
  <xs:field xpath="ID"/>
```

Gives the correct error message. I was focusing on the wrong thing...